# Create an instance using a subset of properties from another instance in a type safe manner?

Tags: c#

I have a data source to which I wan't to bind a collection of X's. X should contain a subset of a certain type Y's properties (let's say Y has properties PropOne, PropTwo, PropThree)
This can of course be done with an anonymous type:

```
void DoBind()
{
   myGrid.DataSource = myCollectionOfYs.Select(y => new {y.PropOne, y.PropTwo});
}
```

How can I modify this method so that the caller of it can specify which properties to use in the projection in a type safe way? I.e. something along the lines:

```
var expressions = new List<Expression<Func<Y, object>>>();
expressions.Add(y => y.PropOne);
expressions.Add(y => y.PropTwo);
DoBind(expressions);
```

Comment: Does it have to be completely dynamic? Or do you have N possible situations?

Comment: So is there a problem in using Func<Y, object> ?

Comment: @Rui It should be dynamic in the sense that the user of the method should have complete freedom to specify any properties to be included in the bound data and should not be forced to change the DoBind method or any of its dependencies.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu How do you mean? How should the implementation of DoBind look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your idea:

```
void DoBind(Func<Y, object> func)
{
    myGrid.DataSource = myCollectionOfYs.Select(funct);
}
```

And use like:

```
DoBind(y => new {y.PropOne});
```

Comment: Of course! I was stuck in thinking that you can't pass anonymous types but nothing preventing passing a function that returns one. :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you not pass in the selector function to the DoBind method:

```
public static void DoBind<T, TResult>(ICollection<T> collection, Func<T,TResult> selector)
{

    DataSource = collection.Select(selector)
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
        DoBind(list, y => new { y.Prop1, y.Prop2 });
        DoBind(list, y => new { y.Prop3, y.Prop2 });
```

Comment: Or also `public  void DoBind<T>(ICollection<T> collection, Func<T,object> selector)`

Comment: Thanks. Same solution as @adrianfaciu who suggested the solution in the comment above.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. It's always a race.